# QGIS Raster Layer - Black rectangle appears as background

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity

[image]I have looked at solutions to what seem to be somewhat similar problems but they don't seem to solve my problem.  A georeferenced raster layer loads into the correct location in relation to other layers, so CRS is obviously OK, but has this black background which I don't know how to remove.

[image]

Comment: Just click on the black area with the information tool, and add the reported value as additional nodata in the layers properties, Transparency tab.

Comment: Is the information tool the Identify Features tool?  I have tried that but nothing seems to happen when I click on the layer.

Comment: Yes, the white `i` in the blue circle. You have to select the raster layer first, then click within the black triangles.

Comment: Have done that as described including layer selection, Andre, and I get a message at the bottom left of the screen "No features at this position found."

Comment: Sorry, Andre, I had the wrong layer selected.Will try again.

Comment: This is the result

Comment: Does it return any values if clicked inside the map area?

Answer (score 8):

**1. Method**

To remove the black border temporarily in QGIS, you can set the "Additional no data value" in Layer properties -> Transparency to `0` (or 000000). If the border is not 100% black you can use the information tool to find out which color you need to set to transparent. If the border is not evenly black, you can use the custom transparent pixel list in the same window below.

[image: Additional No Data Value]

**2. Method**

If you like to permanently remove the black border in your image by adding an alpha channel, you can use the GDAL Tool `nearblack`: Go to Raster -> Analysis -> Near Black and set the in- and ouputfile, then use the edit pen to add `-setalpha` and `-of GTiff`.

`nearblack -of GTiff -setalpha -o output.tif input.tif`

[image: Near Black]

(Of course you need to set output.tif and input.tif to your needs)

Comment: I have tried your "-setalpha" Near Black process. The process runs using my input and output files but just keeps returning the same black background? Do you know why this may be?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work for me too, raising a warning about Formats. But it works when the output format (-of) is specified. I updated the answer accordingly. Please try this :-)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Add the None band and set the RGB values to 0-0-0, Certainly the black background goes.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, creating a none band and setting the RGB values at 0 - 0 -0 allows you to cleanly remove the black border without detail loss from the map itself. Good work.