# Removing black background and black font from raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster where I want to remove the black background.

I tried it with setting `"Additional no data value"` in Layer properties -> Transparency to `0`.

But the place names on the raster are also black and they disappear as well. Is there another method that would work here?

Comment: Have you already seen this topic [QGIS Raster Layer - Black rectangle appears as background](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234590/qgis-raster-layer-black-rectangle-appears-as-background?rq=1)?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a polygon that delineates the valid raster pixels and then use QGIS' `Clip Raster by Mask layer` in order to remove the background. You can find this tool in the menu `Raster / Extraction`. Remember also to assign an non-zero noData value and to tick the "Clip the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline".