# Displaying or generating virtual grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have created a virtual raster in QGIS V3.22.13 from existing individual georeferenced TIF files (3 bands) using the "Generate virtual raster" raster tool (see illustration) >

[image: virtual raster]

The border areas without raster data are obviously filled with "black; RGB 0,0,0"!

Did something go wrong during creation or can any setting be made in the display where these "areas" can be hidden?

Comment: @stefan In QGIS you can set the “Additional value without data”. [In QGIS können Sie den „Zusätzlichen Wert ohne Daten“ festlegen] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234590/qgis-raster-layer-black-rectangle-appears-as-background

Comment: thx! i got it ;-)